# How to change the Text Wrap default in Pages

Tags: pages

When I add a picture to document in Pages, the Text Wrap is always Automatic. I want to set "Above and Below" to be default. How can I do this?

The version is 5.5.1(2111)

[image: The screen shot]

Comment: Good question. No decent answer. May I suggest you to place a request for improvment here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Pages '09` (version 4.3 ¹):

1. Select a picture
2. Configure it completly as you wish
3. Define it as the default image style:

   `Format > Advanced > Define Default Image Style`

[image: Define Default Image Style]

---

With `Pages 5` (version 5.5.1):

1. This function is missing.
2. The creation of an `Image Style` doesn't permit to save the `Text Wrap` tuning.

---

¹)  I removed my installation of `Pages '11` due to its lack of functions. Its documentation isn't available on the Apple web server: [Pages manuals](http://support.apple.com/manuals/#pages).

Comment: my pages version is 5.5.1(2111). I cannot find `Define Default Image Style` option

Comment: The most approaching function within `Pages 5` is: `Format > Advanced > Create Image Style`. But it is a failure to answer your legitimate need. I have the same basic need and use it everytime I include an image with `Pages '09`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using OS X El Capitan and I have been puzzled by this strange lack of function in one of my Pages documents, created originally in 2016. I cannot get access to images contained in this document. The change happens in Format. There is no option in left bar to alter image.

I have placed a different image in the document and this is when the image function appears. There is a text box around the image in the older document (No left bar for image manipulation). This text box has been introduced at some point since 2016. To solve this issue, I pasted another image into the document and the Image manipulation bar appears.

[Create image Style missing][[image]

[create image style is present]

when I add a new image. Both were JPEGs

[[image: create image style is now present[2]]

This changed when I added a new jpgJPG image.